# CSS Background Color of Div Tag Does Not Filled all the axis

Tags: html, css

I have a good problem in css design which I cannot figure out how to fix it.

And it is the same problem in this forum:
[image]

I observed that the header background does not fully filled its horizontal scope when its zoomed in. Below is the zoomed out view of the site.

[image]

This is very the same with my case when designing my header and footer background.
[image]

My HTML Code is:

```
<div id="footerBack">
        <div id="footer">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/eyecolor.png" alt="Eyecolor Icon" /></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" id="terms">Terms &amp; Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="privacy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="news">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="footerAbout">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="footerContact">Footer</a></li>
           </ul>
           <p id="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2012 Jed Designs</p>
           <a href="#"><p id="email">Email: jedlovescpe@gmail.com</p></a>
        </div>
    <div id
```

My CSS:

```
 /*Footer*/
#footerBack         {background: url(images/footerBack.jpg) repeat-x; height: 48px;  position: relative; top: -4px;};
#footer             {padding-top: 10px;}
#footer ul, #footer img
            {margin-top: 5px;}
#footer ul          {float: left; margin-left:160px; margin-top: 15px;}
#footer li a        {color: #d6b85e; padding: 7px; margin: 0 8px 0 8px; font: 11px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;}
#footer li a:hover  {background:#d6b85e; color: #73401f;}
#footer img         {float: left;}
#footer #copyright, #footer #email      
            {float: right; color: #e5dca9; font: 10px "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-right: 12px;}
#footer #email      {margin-top: 2px;}
#footer #copyright  {margin-right: 20px; margin-top: 12px;}
```

What will I do to fix this design problem? :D

Comment: There really isn't a lot you can do other than forcing the width beyond 100%. What is happening is the page is rendering that header the width of the screen since technically the document size hasn't changed just it's magnification the CSS says the document is still x wide even though it is substantially wider than that on screen. Set the width of your footer to 5000px then zoom in, you won't have the shrinking issue the problem is you'll now have a horizontal scroll bar for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce that issue on stackoverflow in IE9. I also don't see any reason it would happen in the code snippet you provided (though there could be something outside of that).

It could very well be an issue with your computer. Do you have another computer handy you could try it out in, just to eliminate that as a possible issue?